# Ошибка при передачи значения Null MySql - Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'id'

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть php код для добавления группы:

```
DataManager::Insert ('groups', array('null',$_REQUEST['new_name'], $_REQUEST['phone']));
```

Я указываю имя, телефон. `Id` по умолчанию `null`.

Но при запросе получаю:

```
Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'id' at row 1
INSERT INTO groups VALUES("null", "mygroup", "333")
```

DataManager::Insert

```
static public function Insert($table, $values, $error_info=1)
    {
        $request = "INSERT INTO $table VALUES(";
        for ($n=0; $n<count($values); $n++)
        {
                    if (trim($values[$n])=="NOW()")
            $request.="NOW()";
                    else
            $request.="\"".addslashes($values[$n])."\"";
                    if ($n<count($values)-1)
                            $request.=", ";
        }

        $request .= ")";

        if ($error_info==1)
        {
            $res = mysql_query($request);
            if ($res==false) die(mysql_error()."<p>$request</p>");      
        }
        else
        {
            try {$res = mysql_query($request);}
            catch (Exception $e){}
        }
```

Comment: Потому что `'null'` это __строка__. Знаете чем строка отличается от `integer`?

Comment: @u_mulder Я то думал что это значение по умолчанию. Кроме того код старый и не мой, я просто настройкой занимаюсь. И по идее он работать должен.

Comment: Строка `'null'` это не значение NULL. Ну и что там делает `DataManager::Insert` смогут угадать только телепаты.

Comment: @u_mulder Специально для вас обновил.

Comment: Если `id` это автоинкремент то его вообще не нужно передавать.

Comment: @u_mulder Они в каждом запросе передают его. Тогда зачем?

Comment: Кто они? Думаете я с ними знаком?

Answer (score 0):

Уберите одинарные кавычки:

```
DataManager::Insert ('groups', array(null,$_REQUEST['new_name'], $_REQUEST['phone']));
```

Comment: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1

Comment: Попробуйте не передавать параметр id, а 2 оставшихся передать как ключ => значение:
DataManager::Insert ('groups', array('new_name' => $_REQUEST['new_name'], 'phone' => $_REQUEST['phone']));
где ключ = имя поля в бд.

Ну и хотелось бы узнать что делает DataManager::Insert.

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка исчезла когда я отключил строгий режим MySQL:

```
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Comment: Мусор пропал, когда я замёл его под ковёр!